# change class conditionally vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a table and I want to change the class depending on the value.

My first approach was to use `v-bind:class="{}` this will change to the right class if true. However doing like this I should create new elements for each value on my table which doesn't look like the best option.

Is there a way to use conditionals, like `if {{value}} > 5 class:something`

I wrote a small [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cosbgn/yzhfhr6s/1/) with how I got it working right now. The idea is that each element in the table will follow these rules without the need of write an if statement for each cell:

```
  if (this.v1 < 4) {
    this.goodBox = true
  } else if (this.v1 < 6) {
    this.goodBox = true
  } else {
    this.badBox = true
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a little on your intent, but something like this.

```
changeClass(value) {
  return {
    'good_box': value <= 4,
    'medium_box': value > 4 && value <= 6,
    'bad_box': value > 6
  }
}
```

Template

```
<table style="width:100%; border:1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td :class="changeClass(v1)">{{v1}}</td>
    <td :class="changeClass(v2)">{{v2}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td :class="changeClass(v3)">{{v3}}</td>
    <td :class="changeClass(v4)">{{v4}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yzhfhr6s/6/).

Answer (score 0):

I would use v-for:

```
<div id="app">
  <table style="width:100%; border:1px solid black">
      <tr v-for="v in values" v-bind:class="{ good_box:v < 4, medium_box:v < 6, bad_box:v >= 6}">
        <td>{{v}}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And simpler app:

```
var test = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { 
    values:[
      3,
      5,
      20,
      15],
  },
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/staszek/ad3yapwq/1/)

Of course you can do two v-for, to generate rows and columns, and modify your data to suit you needs.

You could also use methods for conditionals, but it's up to you.